# PirvateRoute in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Could someone rewrite code snippet from react-route docs into class which i have better understanding of.

`

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      fakeAuth.isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: "/login",
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);
```

`

I tried but I've `TypeError: instance.render is not a function` and i don't know what should be changed, I'am a newbie to JS and React.

`

```
class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return(<Route path={this.props.path}  render={props => {
          if(store.getState().loginReducer.loggedIn === true){
              return <Component component = {this.props.component} />
          }
          else{
              let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
              if(token){
                  let receivedAt = localStorage.getItem("receivedAt");
                  if(Date.now() - receivedAt < 120*60*1000){
                      this.props.dispatch(validateLogin(token));
                      return(<LoadingSpinner/>);
                  }
                  else {
                      return <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: {from: props.location}}}/>;
                  }
              }
              else{
                  return <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location }}}/>;
              }
          }
        }}/>)
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

- Have you imported all the required libraries (react, react-dom, react-router-dom)?
- Are you importing other components (LoadingSpinner, etc)?
- Are you exporting ProtectedRoute?

You will not be able to render anything if this is not followed and your project is not set up correctly.

> I'am a newbie to JS and React.

Don't start with a router then. Start fresh to do a simple app to show just one page, a hello world app would suffice.

Try these 2 tutorials, and always follow the guidelines and check how to use components properly using the [Official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html):

- [Tutorials point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/)
- [React Official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html)

Comment: Yup, I've has everything you are asking for. I'am newbie means i don't work with react. Sorry I had to put this because stackoverflow was angry that most of the post was code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that with `<Component component = {this.props.component} />` is something wrong. I took this from react-route docs so I was expecting this to work.
**The answer is**
`const ComponentToRender = this.props.component;
 return <ComponentToRender/>;`

And full working code form question.

```
class ProtectedRoute extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
    }
    render(){
        return(<Route path={this.props.path}  render={props => {
          if(store.getState().loginReducer.loggedIn === true){
              const ComponentToRender = this.props.component;
              return <ComponentToRender/>;
          }
          else{
              let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
              if(token){
                  let receivedAt = localStorage.getItem("receivedAt");
                  if(Date.now() - receivedAt < 120*60*1000){
                      this.props.dispatch(validateLogin(token));
                      return(<LoadingSpinner/>);
                  }
                  else {
                      return <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: {from: props.location}}}/>;
                  }
              }
              else{
                  return <Redirect to={{pathname: "/login", state: { from: props.location }}}/>;
              }
          }
        }}/>)
    }
}
```